# Explanation of the formula for horizontal sundials

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

I am researching sundials and the maths behind them. For horizontal sundials (ones that stand perpendicular to the equator) there is a formula to compute the hour angles (the angle between the shadow at noon hour [which is always to the true north] and the shadow at hour $t$):
$$\tan(\theta)=\sin(L)\tan(15^\circ\times t)$$
in which

- $\theta$ is the angle between the shadow at noon hour and the shadow at $t$ hour;
- $L$ is the latitude;
- $t$ is the hour you're computing the hour angle for.

I don't understand the intuition behind this formula. Purely mathematically (geometrically) seen, how does it work?
I'm familiar with spherical geometry.

Comment: Perhaps it is a useful approximation: can a sundial tell the correct time on *more than one* day?

Comment: @WeatherVane It's only an approximation if you expect a plain sundial to indicate mean solar time. That formula is exact for a sundial that shows local apparent solar time.

Comment: Please see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sundial).

Comment: That Wikipedia article is quite good, also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_projection The various sundial societies have explanations, too. Eg, https://sundialsoc.org.uk/discussions/

Comment: BTW, a horizontal sundial is parallel to the horizon. So a horizontal dial at the equator is perpendicular to the equatorial plane, but one at the north or south pole is parallel to the equatorial plane.